# Calculate the price of a product from a multilevel BOM

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm not very advanced on sql, i read a lot about cte and recursive query to expand a bom but i still can't figure out how to solve my problem.

My table look like this:

| DB_PARENT | DB_COMPONENT | DB_COEFF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S135427 | M134842 | 0,05122125 |
| S135695 | M134905 | 0,2871687 |
| F133818 | S135482 | 0,5 |
| S135424 | S135423 | 1 |
| S135424 | M134534 | 1 |
| F133783 | S135454 | 1 |
| F133924 | S178585 | 1 |
| S135602 | S135599 | 1 |
| S135087 | M134609 | 0,068 |
| F133353 | M134684 | 0,085867225 |
| F133513 | S135287 | 1 |
| S178407 | M134591 | 2 |
| S135438 | M178128 | 9,663 |
| S135619 | S135622 | 1 |
| S135619 | S135628 | 1 |

I need to calculate the price of every product present in the column DB_parent.

Each product can be composed of either a raw material or another semi-finished product.

Some products on db_parent column have more than 1 row because they can be composed of more than 1 thing (raw material or semi-finisched).

I need to break down each product to reach the raw material and multiply it by the 'db-coeff' column.

So for example if a product is made from a raw material and a semi finisched, i have first to mutiply the raw materiale per the db-coeff, then look at how is made the semi finisched and calculate the semifinisched then add the two.

How can i do this?
I am becoming crazy

thanks

I tried some recursive query but they don't work good
This is the query i tried:

```
with a as(
  SELECT [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_PARENT, [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT, 1 * [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COEFF as price, 1 as level,
  convert(varchar(max), [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT) as path
  FROM [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE]
 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_PARENT, [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT, 1 * [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COEFF as price, a.level + 1 as level,
  a.path + '/' + [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT
  FROM a
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE] ON a.DB_PARENT = [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT)
select DB_PARENT, sum(price), level from a
group by DB_PARENT, level
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please only paste text. Please also include expected results.

Comment: please show the query that you have tried

Comment: this is the table:
DB_PARENT DB_COMPONENT DB_COEFF
S135427 M134842 0,05122125
S135695 M134905 0,2871687
F133818 S135482 0,5
S135424 S135423 1
S135424 M134534 1
F133783 S135454 1
F133924 S178585 1
S135602 S135599 1
S135087 M134609 0,068
F133353 M134684 0,085867225
F133513 S135287 1
S178407 M134591 2
S135438 M178128 9,663
S135619 S135622 1
S135619 S135628 1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in manufacturing and you are referring to Bill Of Materials? If so, so am I, so this works out for us. If not, I apologize.

You are close. The CTE needs to first have an Anchor as the first query above your UNION. This Anchor should be a select to all parent assemblies that have a bill of material.

The second statement after the UNION should be the members that are within the hierarchy of the parent assemblies (Anchor statement)

After you UNION, I noticed you did: 
`INNER JOIN [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE] ON a.DB_PARENT = [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_COMPONENT)` 
However we are going from the parent to the child, so reverse it to:
`INNER JOIN [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE] ON [dbo].[ANAG_DBASE].DB_PARENT = a.DB_COMPONENT)`

```
DECLARE @ASSEMBLY nvarchar(30) = 'S135423';
;WITH CTE_BOM AS (
    SELECT 
        DB_PARENT, 
        DB_COMPONENT, 
        DB_COEFF, 
        1 AS [lvl], 
        CAST(DB_PARENT + '-->' + DB_COMPONENT as nvarchar(max)) as PATH
    FROM ANAG_DBASE 
    WHERE DB_PARENT = @ASSEMBLY --comment this row out if you want all of your assemblys' BOMs blown out
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.DB_PARENT, 
        c.DB_COMPONENT, 
        c.DB_COEFF,  
        [lvl] = b.lvl + 1, 
        PATH + '-->' + c.COMPONENT_ID
    FROM CTE_BOM b
    INNER JOIN ANAG_DBASE c ON b.DB_COMPONENT = c.DB_PARENT
)
```